# how to use next.js path aliases with mocha

Tags: javascript, rest, next.js, mocha.js

I'm creating a next.js webapp and I want to unit test the API routes with mocha. however, mocha doesn't seem to like my path aliases.
(ex. `import prisma from "@/lib/PrismaClient"`)

any suggestions?